# Simulating a COM port in JAVA, C++ or C#?

Tags: java, c++, c, serial-port

Hi so I have a piece of software I need to integrate with but the problem is the information I want is being sent to a COM port which I need to intercept or simulate to get because that COM port might not be connected to anything. Is there any possible way I can simulate and pretend to be a COM port and hear what that software has to say?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is tag spamming..

Comment: Its not tag spamming I'm trying to simulate a COM port and I need to do it using either one of those 4 languages. If its possible in any I think its reasonable to ask people who have experience in any of them.

Comment: Post what you've tried in any of those languages and then it's not tag spamming.  As it is, you've tried nothing and are trying to use SO users as your own personal search engine.

Comment: FYI I've tried to sniff traffic with C on COM port it doesn't work I'm trying to see if anyone on SO has experienced this before. It's asking for help / opinions. I don't see the purpose of stackoverflow if I can't ask for help.

Comment: @user3053234 "it doesnt work" doesn't tell us much, plus you haven't added any code. Please **show what you've tried** and ask a specific question about **code you've written**. Questions like this are way too broad and not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on Windows, use [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to create 2 emulated COM ports (call them COM8 and COM9) on your machine.  They are created to be connected to each other, so you just need to route your application to output to COM8, then listen on COM9 with the software you're writing.

Comment: Thank you, finally someone who gives a useful response :)